# CollapsingToolbarLayout, Android ViewPager and EditText -> Smooth Scrolling(vertical scroll) Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have the following layout design. Here the ViewPager contains fragments with couple of EditText.

My problem is because of EditText(android:enabled="false") the vertical scrolling is not working properly (smoothly). If i remove the EditText and replace with TextView than scrolling with work properly.

My Observation is that EditText consumes the focus event and hence the vertical scrolling is not working. If i touch some area where edittext is not thr than the scrolling will be smooth.

How can i get smooth scrolling with EditText in Fragment in ViewPager with CollapsingToolbarLayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/mProgressBarForImageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:progressDrawable="@color/backgroundColor_white"
                    android:progressTint="@color/backgroundColor_white"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilePicImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/default_profile_pic"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

One of the fragment used is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Phone No." />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneNoEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Father Phone No." />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fatherPhoneNoEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mother Phone No." />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/motherPhoneNoEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/updateButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Update"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `editText`, you can try this:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```